# MongoDB doesn't work with Symfony app in Docker

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I have a Symfony app for a REST API that run in Docker container.

All routes works but when I try to access a route for add information in database or extract information from database I receive the message

```
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

docker-compose file created* with [PHPDocker](https://phpdocker.io/) is

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.0
    container_name: mongo
    command: mongod --smallfiles
    expose:
      - 27017

  webserver:
    tty: true
    image: phpdockerio/nginx:latest
    container_name: code-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
    - "8000:80"

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: phpdocker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    container_name: code-php-fpm
    ### MOVE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES HERE
    environment:
      SYMFONY__MONGO_ADDRESS: mongo
      SYMFONY__MONGO_PORT: 27017
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

*I tried to added links to mongo image, but doesn't work.

Result of command `docker-compose up`.

```
PS E:\API\web_server\code> docker-compose up
Starting code-php-fpm
Starting mongo
Starting code-webserver
Attaching to mongo, code-php-fpm, code-webserver
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.947+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/
db 64-bit host=5c9a4a252688
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.947+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.14
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.947+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 08352afcca24bfc145240a0fac9d28b978ab
77f3
code-php-fpm | [22-Apr-2017 23:11:52] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 5
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.947+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-30-223-232 3.2.0-4-amd64
#1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.947+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
code-php-fpm | [22-Apr-2017 23:11:52] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.947+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { mmapv1: { smallFiles: true
} } }
code-php-fpm | [22-Apr-2017 23:11:52] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.959+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:52.959+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery n
eeded
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:53.395+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:53.395+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
mongo        | 2017-04-22T23:11:53.653+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Log when I tried to access a simple page `(localhost:8000)` from application - it's ok

`code-php-fpm | 172.19.0.4 -  22/Apr/2017:23:24:52 +0000 "GET /app.php" 200`

Log when I tried to access an url `(localhost:8000/transactions/user=invalid&day=1492453903&threshold=100)` valid but with invalid data - it's ok

`code-php-fpm | 172.19.0.4 -  22/Apr/2017:23:23:32 +0000 "GET /app.php" 400`

Log when I tried to access an url `(localhost:8000/transactions/user=100&day=1492453903&threshold=100)` valid with a valid data from insert in mongo database - isn't ok

`code-php-fpm | 172.19.0.4 -  22/Apr/2017:23:13:09 +0000 "GET /app.php" 500`

'parameters.yml' file

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    mongodb_server: 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
```

`config.yml` file contain

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "%mongodb_server%"
            options: {}
    default_database: hootsuite_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                DBBundle: ~
```

Logs from Symfony project:

```
[2017-04-23 07:03:25] request.INFO: Matched route "db_transaction_gettransactions". {"route":"db_transaction_gettransactions","route_parameters":{"_controller":"DBBundle\\Controller\\TransactionController::getTransactionsAction","_route":"db_transaction_gettransactions"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/transactions/?day=1492453903&threshold=123&user=500","method":"GET"} []
[2017-04-23 07:03:25] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-04-23 07:03:25] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception MongoConnectionException: "Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused" at /application/vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Connection.php line 282 {"exception":"[object] (MongoConnectionException(code: 71): Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused at /application/vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Connection.php:282)"} []
```

When I try to view database with Robomongo on `localhost:27017` works.

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: 500 means internal server error. I think you're missing logs from Symfony... Have you checked `/project/var/logs` ?

Comment: The app dosen't connect to MongoDB. I posted the logs in post. How I can do that?

Comment: It's still trying to connect to "localhost:27017" instead of "mongo:27017". Can you post your `app/config/config.yml` file?

Comment: If robomongo works for you, then that might mean you have two mongodb services running. One on your host machine and another in a container. Anyway, in order for PHP to reach mongo, you need to tell your framework, Symfony, that the mongo host is called `mongo`, NOT `localhost`.

Comment: I changed mongodb_server from 'mongodb://localhost:27017' to 'mongodb://mongo:27017' and created again containers but error persist. I should change in another place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're setting environment variables on the nginx server instead of the php/symfony server
2. Your links are also on the nginx server. 
   The good news is that newer versions of `docker-compose` don't require you to use links anymore. `docker-compose` creates a bridge network by default for your project. All services running on this bridge network have the ability to connect to each other by default.

I got rid of these `link` blocks and moved the environment variables from nginx to php.

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.0
    container_name: mongo
    command: mongod --smallfiles
    expose:
      - 27017

  webserver:
    tty: true
    image: phpdockerio/nginx:latest
    container_name: code-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
    - "8000:80"

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: phpdocker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    container_name: code-php-fpm
    ### MOVE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES HERE
    environment:
      SYMFONY__MONGO_ADDRESS: mongo
      SYMFONY__MONGO_PORT: 27017
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Comment: Same error. I changed the content with docker-compose.yml with your content. I posted logs from Symfony. The app doesn't connect to MongoDB. How I can do that?